# Eclipse CDT ranged for

Tags: c++, for-loop, g++

I'm trying to write an answer to an exercise in the C++ Primer. Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
vector<int> v1;
vector<int> v2(10);
vector<int> v3(10, 42);
vector<int> v4{10};
vector<int> v5{10, 42};
vector<string> v6{10};
vector<string> v7{10, "hi"};

for(auto i : v2)
    cout << v2[i] << " " <<;

return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting a generic "syntax error" at the for loop. I've tried all combinations of declaring i as `int` and declaring `&i`, but no luck. The book made a similar `for` loop like so:

```
vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
for (auto &i : v)
    i *= i;
for (auto i : v)
    cout << i << " ";
cout << endl;
```

What am I doing that's different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you misunderstood how the loop works. i is not the index. i contains a copy of the current element of the vector. just try:

```
for(auto i : v2)
    cout << i << " " <<;
```

and if you want to modify the content of your vector you should take the element by reference:

```
for(auto& i : v2)
{
    ++i;
    cout << i << " " <<;
}
```

Edit:
what compiler are you using? if it´s mingw you will have to enable c++11 features with -std=c++11